# Gravity Forms Webhooks - Modify Data

Tags: wordpress, hook, gravity-forms-plugin

The data expected by the API I am posting to needs to be structured in a way that it is wrapped in a root object and a row array. I need to restructure the data provided by the feed prior to it being posted.

I need to format the request to look like this

```
{
    "root": {
        "row": [
            {
                "Ref_Id": "test123",
                "First_Name": "Test",
                "Last_Name": "Post",
                "Mobile": "1234567890",
                "Zip_Code": "12345",
                "Notes": "This is a test post"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But after posting, this is what is being sent

```
[body] => {"Ref_Id":"test123","First_Name":"Test","Last_Name":"Post","Mobile":"1234567890","Zip_Code":"12345","Notes":"This is a test post"}
```

I tried hooking into the filter [gform_webhooks_request_data](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_webhooks_request_data/)

```
add_filter( 'gform_webhooks_request_data_11', 'modify_data', 10, 4 );
function modify_data( $request_data, $feed, $entry, $form ){
  
  $wrapper_open = '{"root":{"row":[';
  $wrapper_close = ']}}';
  
  return $wrapper_open . $request_data . $wrapper_close;
}
```

but this does not work

```
[body] => "{\"root\":{\"row\":[Array]}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been stuck with this question myself for months and I've found the solution.

Gravity Plus make this excellent plugin that allows for outbound webhooks in raw format with merge tags which means you can configure the schema whatever way you need.

This can be great for posting data between Gravity Forms which the API and the limitations of the Webhooks add-on don't actually let you do.

Here's a link to the plugin
https://gravityplus.pro/gravity-forms-post-to-3rd-party/plugin-support/

in this case, you simply activate the add-on, turn it from JSON to Raw mode and put in:

```
{
"root": {
    "row": [
        {
            "Ref_Id": "test123",
            "First_Name": "Test",
            "Last_Name": "Post",
            "Mobile": "1234567890",
            "Zip_Code": "12345",
            "Notes": "This is a test post"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Just replace the values with merge tags.